# How to show and filter magento review according to specific stars

Tags: php, magento

I have a store in magento.
we have applied star reviews in our magento product page. In our product page we have only one value that is quality. Each customer review product within 5 stars. We want to display each star value in percentage.

For example:-
if i have 3 reviews and out of 3, two reviews has 1 star and we want to show one star as 1 star- 50% and same if 3 reviews has 2 stars then we will display 2 stars- 30% like this.

I do not know how can i achieve this in magento reviews. i got rating_summary that is fine. how can i find rating value per star.

And after that i want to filter them according to star reviews if i click on 1 then only one star reviews will display or if i click on 2 star then 2 star reviews will display.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the block `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List` and add then add following methods to calculate the avg

```
public function getAvgReviewRatings(){
    return $this->calculateReviewRatings('avg');
}

public function getStarReviewRatings(){
    return $this->calculateReviewRatings('star');
}

private function calculateReviewRatings($params){
    $star = array('one'=>0,'two'=>0,'three'=>0,'four'=>0,'five'=>0);
    $avg = 0;

    $reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review') 
    ->getResourceCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addEntityFilter('product', $this->getProductId())
    ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
    ->addRateVotes()
    ->setDateOrder();

    $ratings = array();
    if (count($reviews) > 0) {
        foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
            foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) {
                switch($vote->getValue()){
                    case 1:
                        $star['one']+=1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $star['two']+=1;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $star['three']+=1;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $star['four']+=1;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        $star['five']+=5;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                $ratings[] = $vote->getPercent();
            }
        }

        if($params == 'avg'){
        return (array_sum($ratings)/count($ratings))/20;
        }else if($params == 'star'){ 
         return $star;
        }
    }

}
```

And you can call and get all the star values by calling those methods from `review/product/view/list.phtml` like

```
    $stars = $this->getStarReviewRatings();
    foreach($stars as $star=>$value){
      echo $star."-".$value; 
    }
```